# Как размещать новосозданные <div> над другими

Tags: css, разработка-игр, flexbox, grid

Я создаю карточную игру. Вот пример карт в руке противника:

```
<div class="enHend" id="enHand"> 
<div class="card" id="card62" onclick="putEnCard(62)"></div>
<div class="card" id="card130" onclick="putEnCard(130)"></div>
</div>
```

Это все обычные пустые div, у которых в свойстве есть `background-image: url(...`

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы карты появлялись над уже существующими при переполнении `div class="enHend"`.

Были попытки как-то через flex это сделать, но новые карты все так же появляются ниже.
Причем что в руке может быть как 1 карта так и 21. (представьте например Дурака, где при взятии карт, карты в руке как бы налезали друг на друга)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы карты появлялись над уже существующими

Предложу такой вариант...

Можно будет еще добавить смещение и пр. визуальные эффекты...

```js
const oh = document.querySelectorAll('article')
let i = 0
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const m = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)
  const o = document.createElement('div')
  o.classList.add('card')
  o.dataset.m = m
  o.dataset.n = n
  oh[i].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', o)
  i = ++i % oh.length
})
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
article {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 165px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: url(https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/playing-cards-set-poker-cards-full-set_589019-40.jpg?w=1380);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -17px -45px;
}
.card[data-m='0'] {
  background-position-y: -45px;
}
.card[data-m='1'] {
  background-position-y: -215px;
}
.card[data-m='2'] {
  background-position-y: -385px;
}
.card[data-m='3'] {
  background-position-y: -555px;
}
.card[data-n='0'] {
  background-position-x: -17px;
}
.card[data-n='1'] {
  background-position-x: -121px;
}
.card[data-n='2'] {
  background-position-x: -225px;
}
.card[data-n='3'] {
  background-position-x: -329px;
}
.card[data-n='4'] {
  background-position-x: -433px;
}
.card[data-n='5'] {
  background-position-x: -537px;
}
.card[data-n='6'] {
  background-position-x: -641px;
}
.card[data-n='7'] {
  background-position-x: -745px;
}
.card[data-n='8'] {
  background-position-x: -849px;
}
.card[data-n='9'] {
  background-position-x: -953px;
}
.card[data-n='10'] {
  background-position-x: -1057px;
}
.card[data-n='11'] {
  background-position-x: -1161px;
}
.card[data-n='12'] {
  background-position-x: -1265px;
}
```

```html
<button>Карта</button>
<section>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

В твоём случае если ты хочешь наложения одних карт над другими, то нужно использовать position: absolute и задавать им разные z-index. На сколько я знаю, через flex у тебя не выйдет накладывать элементы друг над другом, так как это ломает поточность.

Ещё как вариант, можно попробовать через transform: translateX(). Более простой способ и с точки зрения оптимизации лучше, поскольку в браузере не будет лишних перерисовок

Comment: Но все это для фиксированых значений. А я то в руку добавляю еще карты. В руке может быть и 1 карта и 21. Вот где у меня проблемы (знаю, сам дурак, надо было написать об этом)